# ASP.Net MVC 3.0 Ajax Action Link OnBegin Function Collect return Value and Append to URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

```
 new AjaxOptions
       {
           OnBegin = "MyFunction",
           Url="/Controller/JSONAction/"+OnbeginRetunrValue,
           HttpMethod="GET"
       }
```

In my Ajax properties, I have On Begin function which returns a value.
I wan tot append that return value to the URl.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I realized i can't get this done the way I have asked.
But the Other way to Achieve it is have regular link and call jQuery Ajax Link

```
function CallActionResult(){
//do your logic
var newparam = //get your new param;
$.ajax({
url:"",
DataType:"JSON",
.....
continue rest of the properties.
});
}
```

this is how, I go this worked for me.